# Is there any shell script which provide me the time difference in minute between received UNIX timestamp and current date-time

Tags: shell, unix, unix-timestamp

I am getting a timestamp for my search and I am converting it using the command `date -d@<timestamp> +"%F %H:%M:%S`. It is providing me the Date and Time correctly, i.e. yyyy-mm-dd H:M:S format but I need to find the time difference (in minutes) between the date-time obtained from timestamp and the current date-time.

Comment: http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html (the *Seconds since the epoch* section)?

Comment: Thanks Biffen for this, but it's showing some weird secons...I need to take date-time from timestamp at run time and take difference with current date time(in minutes). Fixing start date won't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

> date +%s

to obtain the current time as a timestamp (seconds from THE EPOCH). Since a unix timestamp is simply a number (of seconds since 1970), you can subtract the two timestamps and divide by 60 to obtain minutes.

If your date command does not support %s, then Biffen comment is helpful.